# Python Segmentation Fault when using json.loads -- alternative way to load JSON into a list?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to load some JSON Twitter data into a list, but instead I'm getting `segmemtation fault (core dumped)`.

While I would love to upgrade my memory, that simply isn't an option right now.  I would like to know if there is some way to maybe iterate over this list instead of trying to trying to load it all into memory?  Or maybe there is a different kind of solution to this problem that will allow me to load this JSON data into a list?

```
In [1]: import json

In [2]: data = []

In [3]: for i in open('tweets.json'):
   ...:     try:
   ...:         data.append(json.loads(i))
   ...:     except:
   ...:         pass
   ...:     

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The data was collected using the Twitter Streaming API over about 10 days and is 213M in size.

Machine Specs:

- Oracle VM Virtual Box
- Operating System: Ubuntu (64 bit)
- Base Memory: 1024 MB
- Video Memory: 128 MB
- Storage (Virtual Size): 8.00 GB Dynamically allocated

I'm using iPython (version 2.7.6), and accessing it through a Linux terminal window.

Comment: It's interesting that it crashes instead of just failing with an exception. Are you able to provide that file somewhere public? I'd really like to look at it.

Comment: 213MB is **tiny**. Can you host that somewhere for perusal?

Comment: What are the specs for the machine you're using to try this?

Comment: What version of python were you using for this? Machine specs?

Answer (score 1):

On almost any modern machine, a 213MB file is very tiny and easily fits into memory. I've loaded larger tweet datasets into memory on average modern machines. But perhaps you (or someone else reading this later) aren't working on a modern machine, or it is a modern machine with an especially small memory capacity.

If it is indeed the size of the data causing the segmentation fault, then you may try the [ijson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson/) module for iterating over chunks of the JSON document.

Here's an example from that project's page:

```
import ijson

parser = ijson.parse(urlopen('http://.../'))
stream.write('<geo>')
for prefix, event, value in parser:
    if (prefix, event) == ('earth', 'map_key'):
        stream.write('<%s>' % value)
        continent = value
    elif prefix.endswith('.name'):
        stream.write('<object name="%s"/>' % value)
    elif (prefix, event) == ('earth.%s' % continent, 'end_map'):
        stream.write('</%s>' % continent)
stream.write('</geo>')
```